# How to check if any item exists in the list

Tags: python

How to check whether a list and an element of a list with such an index exist in the list itself?

```
 I have a list [[10,10,9], [10,10,10], [10,10,10]]
```

Then I enter the number of coordinates (k) and the coordinates themselves. At these coordinates, I have to subtract 8 from the cell and 4 with each cell standing next to it. But what if there are no cells nearby?
When checking if field [r + f] [c + s] in field: it always gives a negative answer. How to make a check?

```
for i in range(k):
    for j in range(1):
        f = drops[i][j]
        s = drops[i][j + 1]
        field[f][s] -= 8
        for r in range(-1, 1):
            for c in range(-1, 1):
                if not (r == c == 1):
                    if field[r + f][c + s] in field:
                        field[r + f][c + s] -= 4
```

Comment: Simple bounds-checking like this is very trivial. Five minutes of thinking should have been more than enough to come up with a solution.

Comment: If `n` is 0 it is the first element, and if `n` is one less than the length of the list it is the last element.

Comment: Are you gicen the element or the index?

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and show it to us, with a description of the problems you have with it.

Answer (score 0):

Slice assignment might help. You have to avoid letting an index go negative, but something like

```
s = slice(max(n-1,0), n+2)
x[s] = [v-1 for v in x[s]]
```

isn't *too* repetitive, while handling the edge cases `n == 0` and `n == len(s) - 1. (It won't work if`n` is *explicitly* set to a negative index, though.)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check whether the index isn't at the start or the end of the list.

```
n = 2
mylist = [4, 5, 8, 9, 12]
if len(mylist) > n+1:
    mylist[n+1] -= 1
if n > 0:
    mylist[n-1] -= 1
```